# How to measure steering angle of a vehicle without using a hardware?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am doing an end-to-end self driving car project using deep learning. After some research, I found out there are some datasets available. However, the dataset contains parameters such as steering angle, speed and the time taken.

So now, I have tried using the dataset to train my model and run the output using a road I have taken in my country. However, the training dataset road were taken in United States and my output road video is from a Malaysian road. Therefore, the steering angle accuracy is not very accurate. This is the current dataset format in .txt file: filename.jpg angle

What can I do with this. Either should I create a new dataset or take an existing one and tune according to the output video?

To create a new dataset, I require parameters such as steering angle. How should I take that without a sensor? Is it possible?

Comment: please post a specific question. Currently you're asking multiple questions at once, and several of them require a lot of background information to properly answer.

Comment: No I just want to know how to measure a steering angle of car on a road without a hardware. Is it possible?

Comment: This is still too broad. If you only have a video input, then NO. If you can connect to the car bus, then it depends on the car type

Comment: yes with an video input, I realized I cant get the steering angle. Is there any way for me to get the steering angle? I dont think i have car bus in my car.

Comment: two cars can have the same turning rate with a different steering angle if they have a different geometry. If you car is not too old, it has a bus. However connecting to the bus and getting the steering data is a non-trivial task.

Comment: you'll need an obd2 sensor that can give you the Steering Angle Sensor readouts.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I will try out

Answer (score 1):

The SA would not matter when it comes to interpreting the road in your country. It will improve the more you train it It is dependable on the structure of your neural network and how you have coded it to learn. It is no mean feat!

By logic it would amend the SA by the boundaries that it will recognize and learn to avoid. It would also need to factor in different variables such as the weight, velocity, tyre, ABS, EPS, TC..etc. There is a phenomenal amount of physic behind it. That is if you want to make a fully functioning safe vehicle anyway. If your making a toy version it wont really matter too much.

Comment: I am trying to make a simulator instead of a fully functional self driving car. This is first my step. Ya as you said, I need to structure my neural network well